# Printing nth line of pascal triangle using recursion

Tags: python, recursion

I was able to make a code printing the pascal triangle from 1 to n (user input), but what I need for the compiler to print is the nth line(the user input). I was having a hard time printing it. Can somebody help me? Here's my code:

```
def pascal(n):
    if n == 0:
        return []
    elif n == 1:
        return [[1]]
    else:
        row = [1]
        result = pascal(n-1)
        row2 = result[-1]
        for i in range(len(row2)-1):
            row.append(row2[i] + row2[i+1])
        row += [1]
        result.append(row)
    return result

n = int(input("Enter a number: "))    
print(pascal(n))
```

Comment: Your code seems to be working. Why don't you just access the last member of `result` - that should be what you're after: `result[-1]`

Answer (score 0):

just  a little hack in print one do `print(pascal(n)[-1])`

this will print nth line

or in your existing code just modify it by

`return [result[-1]]`

this will return you nth line.